# XML : replace values with contents of another xml file to make a new file

Tags: xml

I have a file called ori.xml:

```
<tags>
  <tag1>value1</tag1>
  <tag2>value2</tag2>
  <tag3>value3</tag3>
  <tag4>value4</tag4>
</tags>
```

and another one called modifs.xml:

```
<tag2>newvalue2</tag2>
<tag4>newvalue4</tag4>
```

and I would like to obtain result.xml:

```
<tags>
  <tag1>value1</tag1>
  <tag2>newvalue2</tag2>
  <tag3>value3</tag3>
  <tag4>newvalue4</tag4>
</tags>
```

A priori I can't know which tag is in modifs.xml (it could be only tag3 for example).
So I need something searching in ori.xml for the tags of modifs.xml and changing the values.
I've searched a way to do that and it seems that PERL or XSLT (that I will have to learn) could help me to do it. Is it the right way and could you help me to begin with?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: XSLT would be a good choice as it's been developed for exactly this purpose: manipulating XML files. This task can also be achieved with XSLT-1.0 only, so you could use almost any XSLT processor with one restriction: your `modifs.xml` must have a single root element. Otherwise you have to use higher XSLT versions.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll learn xslt.

Answer (score 0):

You would create an xsl file that will transform ori.xml. The xsl file will need to have a param or attribute that has the values of the modifs file:

```
<xsl:param name="modif_tag"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="document('modifs.xml')/tags" />
</xsl:param name="modifs"/>
```